Black spots appearing on the surface of my 3d Model after importing it from blender to Roblox Studio
I am new to 3d models, recently I created a model using a cylinder and modified it to my liking and after checking the normals to see if there are any inverted faces, I imported it to Roblox Studio in .fbx format. The black spots wont appear when the mesh is scaled down or up completely. Any size in Between causes the black spots to appear. I don't know if the problem is with the lighting or am i doing something wrong while importing.
The model when it is Not scaled up/down to the max :

Blender Info :



Object :


fbx export settings regarding smoothing :

The Blend File:

Solutions I tried:

Checking the Normals
Set the Scale when importing to roblox studio to 0.01
Applying transformations, scale to the object in blender


Sorry, is this how it looks in Roblox? We can help you with Blender here, not Roblox. To me this looks like the upper version has smoothed shading and the lower one flat shading - that is how it would seem to me in Blender. But what Roblox does with shading and if scale has an influence on it I don't know and is off-topic on this site.

@GordonBrinkmann I posted it here, because in roblox forms there are certain conditions to be met for new users to ask questions . I was unable to find anything about it after searching through various online forms and tutorials. So i thought i could ask here due to blender being involved. Anyway thanks for your info, I will try changing the lower one to smooth shading and check if that makes any difference.             I will make sure to not post questions which are regarded off-topic on this site from now on

The problem is, even if this is something that depends on what you  did to this object in Blender, we cannot check your Blender settings for problems if you only show us the Roblox result.

@GordonBrinkmann Thanks for the tip, I forgot to add the object info to the post, have done it now. The scene statistics, dimensions, scales and topology are enough when posting a question regarding a 3d model or are there more stuffs I must include when asking questions regarding 3d models

Your question says, you've checked the normals. Did you check them in Blender or Roblox or both? To me everything seems fine in Blender, but how are your FBX export settings regarding Smoothing_? But the problem still remains and might not be answerable on this site, how Roblox handles smooth/flat shading and sharpened edges.

@GordonBrinkmann I checked them on both Blender and Roblox. I have added an image to my post for the fbx export settings regarding smoothing

@Tere_incipit I checked your object, and other than four loose vertices, I couldn't find anything wrong with it.

@HarryMcKenzie Thanks for checking, I didn't know there were four loose vertices. I think i might have forgotten to either delete them or connect them after using extrude or something

Seems to be a bug in Roblox. Check out this link:      https://devforum.roblox.com/t/voxel-shading-with-artifacts-on-meshparts-even-on-shadowmap-and-future-lighting/2213679   and this one:   https://devforum.roblox.com/t/meshes-with-intensely-dark-circular-shadows/218998/2

I’m voting to close this question because this is likely a Roblox bug. On the Blender side of things there seems to be no problem.

@3fingeredfrog hello, thanks for the links, it clarified that the problem was with the lighting in the game engine and not my blender object. The problem seems to be solved, when I remove the simulation to cast shadows on it, but with the cost of not having proper shadows. There seems to be a less optimizing way to overcome this but it impacts player performance it seems
